# Regarding Triggers in salesforce

Tags: trigger

The below code is working, but the order Must have only one Order Pricebook,if the Order gets activated, new record is Created for below code

```
trigger createorderpricebook on Order (after update) {

    List<Order> orderList = new List<Order>();
    for(Order o : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Order_Pricebooks__r) FROM Order WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]){
        // if there are no any child records, collect ids
        if(o.Order_Pricebooks__r.isEmpty()){
            orderList.add(o);
        }
    }

    List<Order_Pricebook__c> orderPriceBookList = new List<Order_Pricebook__c>();
    //  iterate over collected records and create child records
    for(Order ce:orderList) {

        if(ce.status =='Activated'){
            Order_Pricebook__c gh = new Order_Pricebook__c();
            gh.name= 'ela';
            gh.Order__c = ce.id;
            gh.Price_Book__c = ce.pricebook2Id;
            orderPriceBookList.add(gh);
        }
    }
    insert orderPriceBookList;
}
```

I want above code some Modifications whenever the order object contains pricebook is Modified,then the pricebook is updated in order_pricebook object also, how to Modify the according to scenario -

Comment: This question looks suspiciously like [Trigger for Bulk of Records](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/132097/trigger-for-bulk-of-records)...

Comment: Sure looks to me like this should be a Before Update trigger. Agree with @AdrianLarson on the question looking very similar.

Comment: Well, [you're supposed to create related data in after triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm). Why do you say before update? @crmprogdev

Comment: You can create the related data in a Before Update trigger too, as in before these records are updated. That way the PriceBooks will exist and will all have the same pricebook as required. If done after, they won't have the same pricebooks at the time they're updated which isn't what he's trying to achieve.